# writing SQL query to show result in specific order

Tags: sql

I have this table

```
+----+--------+------------+-----------+
| Id | day_id | subject_id | period_Id |
+----+--------+------------+-----------+
| 1  | 1      | 1          | 1         |
| 2  | 1      | 2          | 2         |
| 8  | 2      | 6          | 1         |
| 9  | 2      | 7          | 2         |
| 15 | 3      | 3          | 1         |
| 16 | 3      | 4          | 2         |
| 22 | 4      | 5          | 1         |
| 23 | 4      | 5          | 2         |
| 24 | 4      | 6          | 3         |
| 29 | 5      | 8          | 1         |
| 30 | 5      | 1          | 2         |


to something like this



| Id | day_id | subject_id | period_Id |
| 1  | 1      | 1          | 1         |
| 8  | 2      | 6          | 1         |
| 15 | 3      | 3          | 1         |
| 22 | 4      | 5          | 1         |
| 29 | 5      | 8          | 1         |
| 2  | 1      | 2          | 2         |
| 2  | 1      | 2          | 2         |
| 16 | 3      | 4          | 2         |
| 23 | 4      | 5          | 2         |
| 30 | 5      | 1          | 2         |
+----+--------+------------+-----------+
```

SO, I want to choose one period with a different subject each day and doing this for number of weeks. so first subject dose not come until all subject have been chosen.

Answer (score 0):

You can `ORDER BY` period_id first and then by `day_id`:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY period_Id, day_Id
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382902)**</kbd>

Comment: but what about the next week...day order 1 2 3 4 5 then 1 2 3 4 5 then 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: @NaifAlblawi Extend your data with next week and show desired output. Anyway you've got day order already